# Import error for scapy on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, scapy

I'm interested in using scapy as a package in my python code. 
I followed the instructions to install it, and here is my python code (actually this is a code taken from another website):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
from scapy import *


ap_list = []

def PacketHandler(pkt) :
      if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
            if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8 :
                  if pkt.addr2 not in ap_list :
                        ap_list.append(pkt.addr2)
                        print("AP MAC: {} with SSID: {} ".format(pkt.addr2, pkt.info))


sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)
```

I get the following error: 
"ImportError: No module named 'scapy' " 
I saw on the previous posts the answers, though, in my case: 
- Scapy is already installed:

```
armand@ACPC:~$ sudo apt-get install python-scapy
[sudo] password for armand: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-scapy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 169 not upgraded.
```

- The directory /usr/share/pyshared contains scapy:

```
armand@ACPC:~$ cd /usr/share/pyshared/
armand@ACPC:/usr/share/pyshared$ ls
scapy  scapy-2.2.0.egg-info
armand@ACPC:/usr/share/pyshared$
```

- Scapy runs on the interpreter:

```
armand@ACPC:/usr/share/pyshared$ scapy
INFO: Can't import python gnuplot wrapper . Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Welcome to Scapy (2.3.1)
>>>
```

There probably is a problem when I import scapy as a library but I don't what it is. I'm running python3.4 on Ubuntu14.04.
Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official scapy project only work with Python 2.x. Here's a Python 3 port: http://github.com/phaethon/scapy

Comment: Thank you very much, StephenG !